# Unit testing Htmx?

Tags: unit-testing, htmx

How do you write unit tests for [Htmx](https://Htmx.org)?

Stack overflow isn't letting me post such a short question, so this paragraph says that I didn't see docs or a library about this.

**EDIT**: Specifically, I wish to unit test in Django.

Comment: I added a new issue, since I think the docs should explain how to test htmx based applications: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/452

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of solutions to this:

- Many server side platforms offer the equivalent of [rails "functional" controller tests](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/master/test/attributes/hx-get.js), and those can be used to test your partial end points, depending on what platform you are using.
- You can write client side javascript tests in the normal manner.  The [htmx test suite](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/master/test/) uses chai.js & mocha.js to create a test suite, and sinon.js to mock out the server side.  If you can run the tests against your actual server, that will simplify things even more.

Broadly, for day to day unit tests, I would lean towards the first approach because it will be more stable and "functional" and then use the second approach for integration testing.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you use some kind of framework. For example Django, Laravel, Ruby on Rails, ...

Just use the tools of your framework to test your http endpoints.

For e2e tests I would use Playwright. But keep in mind this rule: 80% unittests, 15% integration tests, 5% e2e tests.

I have one e2e test which checks to happy path.

And a lot of pytest-django based tests.

For forms I use this pattern: [html_form_to_dict](https://github.com/guettli/django-tips/blob/main/README.md#html_form_to_dict)

Maybe this question gets better answers in the discord channel, since there is no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternate responses between JSON and HTMX based on the Content-Type header. This approach allows you to utilize the canonical tests provided by the web framework while also offering JSON endpoints.

Here's an example for Go with the Echo framework:

```
func Render(c echo.Context, code int, name string, data interface{}) error {
    contentType := c.Request().Header.Get("Content-Type")
    if contentType == "application/json" {
        return c.JSON(code, data)
    }
    return c.Render(code, name, data)
}
```